# PasswordResetView.as_view Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

## urls.py

```
url(r'^password/reset/$',
    PasswordResetView.as_view(
        success_url=reverse_lazy('password_reset_done'),
        template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
        email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
        subject_template_name='registration/email/password_reset_subject.txt'
    ),
    name='password_reset'),

url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
    PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html'
    ),
    name='password_reset_done'),
```

## error

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/password/reset/done/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

 File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)

 File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)

 File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)

 File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)

 File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)

 File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)

  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
result = block.nodelist.render(context)

 File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 458, in render
url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

"GET /accounts/password/reset/done/ HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Comment: Can you also paste code from your apps *urls.py*?

Comment: @kiran.koduru added the urls code

Comment: Thanks. Are you adding the URLs to the variable `urlpatterns`? Or is that your full *urls.py* file?

Comment: That's the url file. adding it into another urls file

Comment: @seenus Please show `registration/password_reset_confirm.html` and the view `PasswordResetDoneView` as well.

Comment: What does adding it to another URLs file mean? Can you paste the file structure for your project?

Comment: @AamirAdnan Using the basic django url template code. I didn't anything extra into urls.

Comment: @seenus I believe `NoReverseMatch` is raised either from `PasswordResetDoneView` or from its template, please check if you are using `reverse` in view or `url` tag in template and double check you are trying to resolve it properly. That's why I have asked you to share the view and template.